# Managing OneDrive Files On Demand with folders and subfolders

Tags: powershell, onedrive

Tried to get all files and subfolders in a folder online. Find this solution which does not work for me:

```
attrib +p -u foldername /s
```

Get no error, but nothing happend. 
Find out it works when using system and hide file attributes:

```
attrib +s -h -p +u foldername\* /s
```

but then got a warning when the folder is empty (not tragic).

I prefer using a solution without specify the folder/filetype. Just want handle all files and folders in a folder.

thanks for any helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are not trying to do this with the files in your local machines OneDrive folder but are instead trying to get the files and folders stored online in OneDrive through the SharePoint Online Management Shell.  If that is correct then I don't think "attrib" works in SPO Management Shell.  If you look [one level up in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/commands-by-server-role) attrib is listed as a Windows Server command, which means it won't work in SPO Management Shell.

You will probably need the PnPPowerShellOnline module:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Force
```

And use a commandlet like:

```
Get-PnPListItem
```

in order to get the actual files in OneDrive.

[This site](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/transfer-users-onedrive-files-another-user-via-powershell/) has a more in depth script that you can use as a guide for interacting with individual files in OneDrive and SPO.

Comment: No has nothing to do with Sharepoint. I am trying to do this with the files on my local machine OneDrive folder.